# Ruby ultra simplistic mail server

Tags: ruby, smtp, email

I am trying to create a simple ruby mail server ( SMTP server) just or fun. I tried the code in the http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3932

I am not able  to sendmail from my machine. I also posted comment there but no reply ;(.

Can any you please help me by giving a pointer or a simple ruby smtp server that can send mail to my gmail account without using a SMTP servers or MTA.

Comment: http://rubygems.org/gems/mini-smtp-server might be useful

Answer (score 0):

Your SMTP server still needs to connect to smtp.gmail.com to forward your mail. The protocol for doing so can be found in RFC821 (http://james.apache.org/server/rfclist/smtp/rfc0821.txt)

It looks like the example above just allows you to connect to the SMTP server on localhost and store mails locally.